# el.cache[] null or not an object

Tags: extjs

hi i have a treePanel on node dblClick listener i am opening a tab panel...it works for the most part but on some occasion i am getting this error el.cache[] null or not an object...does any one have any idea on how to solve this problem..please help

Comment: check which component is causing the error, is it TreePanel or your TabPanel.. you can make use of firebug...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an event isn't being cleaned up.  Make sure that if you are listening to an event for a node in the tree, that the event will be cleaned up (that is, "unlistened") properly if the tree gets reloaded.

Are you ever reloading nodes in the tree?  If so, I'd check any events tied directly to nodes.

If not, try and let us know if you are doing anything else funny with the tree, and see if you can post some code.